# see a remote form in another computer in vb .net

Tags: vb.net, remote-desktop

Morning everyone. I'm in doubt if exist a way in VB .net to see what happens in a form  on another computer, I'll explain, I made a form to get some values, this is in a production computer but I want to see what is happening in that screen on my own computer.

Comment: Why not remote into the machine and look?

Comment: and if you can't remote in, then write your data to a log file or database somewhere on the network that you can access.